# Merge branch from fork point

Tags: git

I have a git repository with a few branches

```
      d - e - f (branch b1)
     /
a - b - c - g - h (branch b2)
             \
              i - j (branch b3)
```

I would like to replay patches `i` and `j` on top of `f` to get

```
      d - e - f - i' - j' (branch b1)
     /
a - b - c - g - h (branch b2)
             \
              i - j (branch b3)
```

but not bring changes `c` and `g` along.

How do I do this? So far, i've been using `cherry-pick` and specify the range manually, but it seems there must be a better way.

Comment: `cherry-pick` is the way to go for your case

Comment: I do not know how are you specifying range but you may want to go over `man gitrevisions` to find a shorter way how to specify range